# Excel VBA Can't create more than 3 conditional formatting rules?

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, conditional-statements

I trying to use to VBA to create a few conditional formatting rules but I keep getting "Subscript out of range" error for the 3rd rule.

This is my current code

```
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim MyRange2 As Range
Dim MyRange3 As Range

'Define the range for the respective rules
Set MyRange = Range("M4:N30")
Set MyRange2 = Range("A4:Z30")
Set MyRange3 = Range("O4:P30")

MyRange2.FormatConditions.Delete

'Rule 1
MyRange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$M4<>""NA""", Formula2:="=$N4<>""NA"""
MyRange.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 150, 0)

'Rule 2
MyRange2.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$O4>56", Formula2:="=$P4>56"
MyRange2.FormatConditions(2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)

'Rule 3
MyRange3.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$O4<>$P4"
MyRange3.FormatConditions(3).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
```

If I change the "3" in FormatConditions(3) to 1 or 2, i dont get errors. Any advise on whats causing the error?

Thank you for your time

Comment: `MyRange3` Seems to be the problem, not the amount of rules.

Comment: `FormatConditions.Add` returns an object reference that  you can use directly instead of relying on counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using:

`MyRange3.FormatConditions(2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)`

because for the range specified i.e. `O4:P30` it is second rule and it gives you error because rule number 3 does not exist!

Comment: Thank you! It worked! But I don't understand what u mean by its the second rule. Like my first rule is for MyRange, second rule is for MyRange2 and now my third rule is supposed to only affect MyRange3

Comment: @ProgrammingPikachu The rules are applied to the Cell, not to the Worksheet.  So, if I had a Rule for "A2:D2", and another rule for "B1:B4", then only cell B2 would have a `FormatConditions(2)`; the rest of the cells would either have *no* condition, or only `FormatConditions(1)`.  This is why you'd be better skipping that, and using `With MyRange.FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$M4<>""NA""", Formula2:="=$N4<>""NA"""): .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 150, 0): End With` — then the number doesn't matter.